# rabbitmq-alerts: stream error: stream ID 95; INTERNAL_ERROR when install rabbitmq using helm

Tags: kubernetes

When I am using helm v3.2.1 to deploy RabbitMQ HA using this command in kubernetes v1.15.2 cluster:

```
./helm install stable/rabbitmq-ha --generate-name -n dabai-pro
```

It shows this error:

```
[miao@MeowK8SMaster1 linux-amd64]$ ./helm install stable/rabbitmq-ha --generate-name -n dabai-pro
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: could not get information about the resource: Get https://192.168.64.248:6443/apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/monitoring/prometheusrules/rabbitmq-ha-1591246489-rabbitmq-alerts: stream error: stream ID 95; INTERNAL_ERROR
```

should I must install prometheus in namespace monitoring? why monitoring component make RabbitMQ install failed? To my understand, monitor component should independent and not affect product component. So what is the proper way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mandatory to install Prometheus.Use below command to install rabbitmq without Prometheus

```
helm install my-release --set prometheus.operator.enabled=false stable/rabbitmq-ha
```